# Como puedo pasar la suma

Tags: php, javascript, json

Tengo una función que manda un array y lo recibe mi otra función suma que saca la sumatoria de ese pero me da `null` cuando lo recibo en mi archivo de php array y lo muestra en un `li` y quiero mandarlo a php pero cuando lo recibo en php me sale `NULL` y tengo otra función que se encarga de convertirlo y mandarlo a php por ajax

```
function sumar(arrayinput) {
var listaT = document.querySelector('#listaT');
listaT.innerHTML = '';
let suma = 0;
for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
    suma += arrayinput[i];
}
var listaLi = document.createElement('li');
listaT.appendChild(listaLi);
listaLi.innerText = suma;

console.log("suma total", suma);
 }
```

acá se encarga de convertirlo y mandarlo a php

```
 function guardarSuma() {
var sumaT = { "data": suma };
var jsonsuma = JSON.stringify(sumaT);
ajaxs("procesos/Procesoventa.php", { "suma": jsonsuma })
    .done(function(info) {
        console.log(info);
    });
  }
```

Comment: No entiendo bien el planteamiento, pero me parece extraño que la función `sumar(arrayinput)` acumula la sumatoria en una variable llamada `suma` y al final devuelve una variable `sumaT` que no está declarada ni es usada dentro de la función.

Comment: es que estaba probando ahorita quito sumaT en la funcion de suma

Comment: quiero mandar la suma del array a mi archivo de php pero primero tengo convertirlo a json

Answer (score 1):

Supongo que necesitas enviar una suma para guardar en php
Bueno te recomiento primero que hagas funciones atomicas que tengan un solo objetivo te mando un ejemplo y con esto deberia funcionar tu codigo.

No diste muchos detalles de donde se ejecuta la suma y donde se llama a guardarSuma(), pero supongo que tu problema se genera porque la variable suma no esta en el scope de guardar suma.

Intenta siempre pasar las cosas por parametro.

Si te sigue tirando null del LADO de PHP, podria ser que necesites usar en ajax.post, ejemplo : ajax.post("procesos/Procesoventa.php",data).done .....
y del lado de PHP acordate que tenes que recuperar la informacion con la variable $_POST["suma"];

Espero que te sirva.

```js
(()=>{

/*Definir funciones atomicas */
function sumar(arrayinput) {
  let suma = 0;
  for (let i = 0; i < arrayinput.length; i++) {
      suma += arrayinput[i];
  }
  return suma;
}

function guardarSuma(suma){
  var sumaT = { "data": suma };
  var jsonsuma = JSON.stringify(sumaT);
  var data = { "suma": jsonsuma };
  console.log(data);
  alert(`guardarSuma envia ...${JSON.stringify(data)}`);
  ajaxs("procesos/Procesoventa.php", data)
      .done(function(info) {
          console.log(info);
  });
}

/*Procesamiento*/
/*Realizo la suma*/
const suma =  sumar([1,2,3,4,5,6]);
/*Guardo la suma*/
guardarSuma(suma);

/*Si necesitas pintar la suma en html Realizar otra function */


})()
```

Comment: tengo una función que llena el array desde HTML por medio de un input se llena el array y eso hace esa función después esa función manda el array a la función de suma y saca la suma total del array

Comment: ya mande ese array en formato JSON a php y ya lo inserte solo me falta la suma del array que es la que quiero mandar

Comment: Lo que hace guardar suma es mandarlo a php y convertirlo a JSON